# How can I put a background image in an NSSavePanel?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'd like to have a background image in the NSSavePanel which I need to satisfy macOS Sandbox file export requirements. Such background image would be reflective of the overall imagery I use in the other application window and sheets. Apple's default NSSavePanel image style is okay for an app that cares little about its style, but my app is directed to video editors who can appreciate an artistic rather than mechanical atmosphere.

I've been able to use the panel's accessoryView property but it only appears as a differentiated section in the panel separate from the panel's overall style.

A simple background image for the panel overall capability would completely suffice, but it doesn't seem possible according to all the Apple Developer documentation. Maybe there's a practical HACK?

Comment: How do you add an image to the other windows? Did you try to do the same with the save panel?

Comment: Yes. Knowing that NSSavePanel derives from NSPanel which derives from NSWindow I tried first to `[myPanel setBackgroundColor:myColor];` which built well but had no effect on the displayed panel. Had it not built well I would have gone further with the trial and error method of development, but because the panel is put up by powerbox not AppKit, I thought there's some disconnect and abandoned experimenting with such approach. No doubt my ignorance is profound and my research is weak, so perhaps there is some proper way to accomplish what I seek. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: I also know I could construct my own panel as a sheet making it appear however I want with the nib, but I rather doubt that the Sandbox requirement for exporting data would work. Perhaps there's some way to involve Sandbox with such 'homemade' sheet/panel. ???

Comment: This code: `[myPanel setBackgroundColor:myColor];` actually works for me in a sandboxed desktop app running on Mojave. My code is simple `NSSavePanel* sp = [NSSavePanel savePanel]; [sp setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]]; [sp runModal];`

Comment: Strangeness!  My code is exactly equivalent to TheNextman's except mine runs with`[myPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:myController.window completionHandler:^(){}` handler etc. So, I tested with simple `runModal` as his does - to no avail, no color.  Also Mojave, but Xcode 10.1. maybe Xcode 10.2 (which I already have) will do better. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: I'm testing on Xcode 10.1. Literally inserted the code above into a brand new project, enabled read/write access to user selected files and ran. I get a save panel with a green background.

Comment: 10.2 did no better, but did give me a Code Signing fault which 10.1 doesn't. Back to 10.1 until this panel issue solved. I had and still have enabled read/write access to user-selected files. So now I will also literally copy your code into my project and see what happens.